# .Net Core 2.1 asp-for with label not working

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

Using Visual Studio 2017, .Net Core 2.1, Web Site

With this model

```
public class TestObj
{
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string str1 { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public int int1 { get; set; }
    public List<TestObj> TestList { get; set; }
    public TestObj() { }
    public TestObj(string i_str, int i_int)
    {
        this.str1 = i_str;
        this.int1 = i_int;
    }
}
```

And this controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
public IActionResult Test()
{
    TestObj model = new TestObj();
    model.TestList = new List<TestObj>();
    model.TestList.Add(new TestObj("test1", 1));
    model.TestList.Add(new TestObj("test2", 2));
    return View(model);
}
```

This as the cshtml:

```
<form asp-action="Test" asp-controller="Home">
<ul>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.TestList.Count; i++)
    {
        <li><label asp-for="@Model.TestList[i].str1" /></li>
        <li><label asp-for="@Model.TestList[i].int1" /></li>
        <li><input asp-for="@Model.TestList[i].str1" /></li>
        <li><input asp-for="@Model.TestList[i].int1" /></li>
    }
</ul>
```

I get the input boxes but not the Labels. I have searched the web and Stack Overflow but can't find out why the labels fail when the inputs work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please feel free to reduce my reputation, it's been one of those days. The asp-for is not appropriate to a LABEL. Not sure about all the gory details but I suspect it should only be applied to html tags that would return a value to the controller. I replaced the asp-for with a simple label <label>@Model.TripletList[i].name</label> and it works.

Answer (score 4):

I was stuck on this one for a bit. The label tag must be closed by another tag, not within the same tag. Otherwise it will not work correctly.

This will **not** work:

```
<label asp-for="Date" class="col-form-label col-sm-3" />
```

This will:

```
<label asp-for="Date" class="col-form-label col-sm-3"></label>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second example be closed with a </label> tag rather than an </input>?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make couple of changes for this

1. As said by SeanTech you have to enclosed `<label>` tags with `</label>`
2. Tag Helpers are imported from @addTagHelper *,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
   it is available in ViewImorts.cshtml.
   Make sure this file should be available in root level of your views/pages
   folders.

The bottom line is this – you need to add this line to your _ViewImports.cshtml file. And you need to make SURE, that the particular _ViewImports file is used for your views or pages folder.